# kmeans based on mapreduce by python

Tags: python, hadoop, mrjob

I am going to write a mapper and reducer for the kmeans algorithm, I think the best course of action to do is putting the distance calculator in mapper and sending to reducer with the cluster id as key and coordinates of row as value. In reducer, updating the centroids would be performed. I am writing this by python.

As you know, I have to use Hadoop streaming to transfer data between `STDIN` and `STOUT`. according to my knowledge, when we `print (key + "\t"+value)`, it will be sent to reducer. Reducer will receive data and it calculates the new centroids but when we print new centroids, I think it does not send them to mapper to calculate new clusters and it just send it to `STDOUT` and as you know, kmeans is an iterative algorithm. So, my questions is whether Hadoop streaming suffers of doing iterative programs and we should employ `MRJOB` for iterative programs?

Comment: KMeans in MapReduce already has many implementations. See [mahout](https://mahout.apache.org/) for example.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I want to implement kmeans by Hadoop,Python and Hadoop streaming

Comment: I know that, what I'm trying to say is to look at the algorithms they used to do the job.

Comment: @user3616059 did you actually do anything? You simple gave no feedback in your other question!